# Equals in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML like this:

```
<div class="paginate">

    <ul>
        <li class="first inactive">
            <a class="page-link" data-number="1">«</a>
        </li>
        <li class="previous inactive">
            <a class="page-link" data-number="1">«</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

I am calling a jQuery function like this:

```
$('.paginate').on('click', 'li a.page-link', function () {

    var self = $(this).parent().parent();

    console.log(self.find('li.first').hasClass('inactive') || self.find('li.previous').hasClass('inactive'));
    console.log(self.find('li.first') == $(this).parent() || self.find('li.previous') == $(this).parent());

}
```

When the call arrives first condition logged in my console is `true`, which is as expected, but the second is always `false` I expect it to be true once I click on the link which has class `first` or `previous`. Why `==` is not working in this case? Is there other way to check the equality of objects in jQuery?

Comment: *"Why == is not working in this case?"* Because two different jQuery objects will *never* be `==` (or `===`) to one another, even if they have the same contents, because they're separate objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
console.log(self.find('li.first').is($(this).parent()) || self.find('li.previous').is( $(this).parent()));
```

or

```
var $parent = $(this).parent();
console.log($parent.is('li.first') || $parent.is('li.previous'))
```